# Real-time image processing using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I just started working on a project where I will need to process frames from a stream of my webcam, so I was just wondering if you knew which library would be suited for this task. So far I've looked at Pixastic which seems okay but I'd like to see what my alternatives are.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

This jQuery plugin may be great help.